# fail to compiled glib

Tags: linux, compilation, gtk, glib

I try to compile glib from source code. But an I/O error stops me.

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/gtk3/glib-2.36.0/docs'
Making all in reference
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/src/gtk3/glib-2.36.0/docs/reference'
Making all in glib
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/src/gtk3/glib-2.36.0/docs/reference/glib'
  GEN      glib-gettextize.1
I/O error : Attempt to load network entity http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl
warning: failed to load external entity "http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl"
cannot parse http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl
make[4]: *** [glib-gettextize.1] Error 4
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/gtk3/glib-2.36.0/docs/reference/glib'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/gtk3/glib-2.36.0/docs/reference'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/gtk3/glib-2.36.0/docs'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/gtk3/glib-2.36.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation cannot be built because the external transform stylesheet `http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl` cannot be loaded.

Try connecting this machine to the Internet and running the build again.

Comment: I follow your advise,but fail again.I can use "wget http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/manpages/docbook.xsl" to get the file,but when I try to compile glib,failed again and the same prompt came out again.

Comment: Perhaps you can configure again to avoid the connection.... And asking on a Gtk or Glib mailing list would be better...

Answer (score 0):

Installing docbook-xls appears to fix the problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get install -y docbook-xsl
```